# primeFaces commandButton styling within a primeFaces toolBar element

Tags: html, primefaces

Basically, I have a set of prime faces commandButtons in a primeFaces toolBar, and I am trying to set the background color of the buttons using an external style sheet to no avail. it does work to add in-line styling saying 'style="background-color:blue;"'. Any help is appreciated thank you.
html Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="../resources/css/homePage.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div class="headline">
        <h1 align="center">Web Project Example</h1>
    </div>
        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:toolbar>
                <f:facet name="left">
                    <p:commandButton value="About Me" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Current Projects" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="right">
                    <p:commandButton value="Example 3" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Example 4" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:toolbar>
        </h:form>
    <p>Example text</p>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Style sheet:

```
body {
    margin:0px;
}
.headline {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
.ui-toolbar {
    background-color:black;
    border:none;
    color:white;
}
.ui-button {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your own stylesheet has to be included last (after Primefaces includes its own styles dynamically) in order to override the standards, so try

```
<h:head>
    <f:facet name="last">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../resources/css/homePage.css" />
    </f:facet>
</h:head>
```

If it does'ent work try putting it inside `<body>` instead.